# Can't find files from my Windows partition

Tags: files

I recently started using Ubuntu for the first time, and I cannot find any of the existing files from my hard drive. I'm running it so I can choose from Windows and Ubuntu on startup.

How do I find all of my files?

Comment: Do you happen to know what the format of the partition of Windows is? If it is NTFS, do type the following in terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T)    sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g. This will install a program that will let Ubuntu read NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Your files can be found at the "XX GB Filesystem" disk on the left panel of Nautilus (the folders browser). Click it, wait for folders to appear and then look for the "Users" folder and, inside it, your user account's name on Windows. If you were on XP, look for "Documents and Settings" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you should checkout which partition was having that data, for that you will have to mount that partition.Tell me if That partition exist or not where you are keeping files?